# Xcode label views in console

Tags: xcode

is there a way for me to "label" views so that I can better identify which of my constraints is having problems?

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bf8a6f0 H:|-(0)-[UIScrollView:0x10bf84a60]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x10bf89940 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bf8a790 H:[UIScrollView:0x10bf84a60(560)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bf8a740 H:[UIScrollView:0x10bf84a60]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x10bf89940 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10f512090 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x10bf89940(320)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bf8a740 H:[UIScrollView:0x10bf84a60]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x10bf89940 )>
```

In this case I found the problem, but it is not always so obvious. Or is the only way for me to NSLog each one with it's pointer address and then compare?

Thanks